# NSKeyedArchiver expected memory usage

Tags: ios, objective-c, foundation, nskeyedarchiver, nskeyedunarchiver

what is the expected memory usage of NSKeyedArchiver during the encoding process ?

in encoding ~4MB of an object graph into an NSData object, Xcode reveals the process uses almost 4-5x the memory just in the process of encoding (which is eventually causing a crash with larger object graphs), but the final, encoded NSData object remains around ~4MB. A picture is attached below, where the massive spike occurs during the encoding process. Is this expected behavior?

[image]

Comment: It depends somewhat (this can be expected). Are you doing any custom encoding? Is this a single call to `archivedDataWithRootObject:` or do you have a loop involved? Do you have a very large number of small objects or a large number of large objects?

Comment: Not doing custom encoding, in the sense that it's just boilerplate NSCoding protocol for all objects in the graph, which are custom subclasses of NSObject. It's a single call to archivedDataWithRootObject, and the bulk of data comes from a very large number (can range between 1-100k) of small objects.

Comment: *** ^ @RobNapier

Comment: Yeah, having huge numbers of objects can cause some issues due to cycle detection. (The other major problem is often related to autorelease pools, but you can't do much about that inside of a single call.) I would probably consider writing something that large to a file (`archiveRootObject:toFile:`) directly rather than into memory. Almost anything you'd want to do with it next would be best done off a file.

Comment: And of course I have to mention that managing massive object trees is what Core Data exists to solve. (But 4MB isn't really all that much data, so…)